# Pandas date time with timezone to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, data-analysis

I am playing with some data. Out of all, two columns make me curious, Datetime and Timezone. Sample data looks like:

```
|-----------------|------------|
| Datetime        | Timezone   |
|-----------------|------------|
| 2446159.1805556 | -5.5000000 |
| 2434633.2902778 | -5.5000000 |
| 2444298.3437500 | -5.5000000 |
| 2442694.3125000 | -5.5000000 |
| 2444622.0604167 | -5.5000000 |
| 2435409.3854167 |  8.0000000 |
|-----------------|------------|
```

While trying to convert these to timestamp format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss), using the code below, I am getting all dates as 1970-01-29:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], unit='s')
```

How can I convert to the right date in the right timezone? I don't know the actual output, but I am certain that all dates are not going to be the same.

Comment: Well that is correct if the unit is `seconds` and the origin is `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, since there are 86,400 seconds in a day and 2.4M seconds is ~29 days. But if you don't know both the units of `Datetime` and the origin it's measured from it's impossible to know what `Date` those should be. I mean those could be minutes since `2010-01-18` for all we know

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Timestamp` class.

```
start = pd.Timestamp(2446159.1805556,unit ='s')
print(start)
```

Output

> 1970-01-29 07:29:19.180555600

Comment: The problem is that all the timestamps convert to date 1970-01-29, which does not seem right to me.